# Selenium IDE - results.html

Tags: selenium-ide

How report my test case results on selenium-ide. I don't want use selenium-rc. What command I should use to get results.html ?

Answer (score 3):

you can use File Logging add-on..With the help of this you can store result of your test case

Answer (score 0):

Use this command, you will get a report for your html suite execution in Selenium IDE

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*chrome" http://www.example.com 
./testsuite.html results.html
```

Here are the argument:

- selenium-server.jar - Selenium server path
- -htmlSuite "*chrome" - Browser used for the test, Firefox is "*firefox"
- http://www.example.com - base URL of your test
- ./testsuite.html - html test suite path
- results.html - path for storing results.html